# CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList() returns null

Tags: java, ubuntu, webcam, jmf

I coded in `java` on `ubuntu 11.10`

Laptop webcam is running correctly and locate it `/dev/v4l/`.
Skype application can use webcam and run.

I installed JMF but i couldn't add environment variables.`

```
Vector deviceList = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(new RGBFormat());
System.out.println(deviceList.toString());
if(!deviceList.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("1");
    device = (CaptureDeviceInfo) deviceList.firstElement();
}
device = (CaptureDeviceInfo) deviceList.firstElement();
ml = device.getLocator();
```

I want to just a capture a image in java.

What should i do solving the problem or use instead of JMF?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(), the available devices must be loaded into the memory first.

You can do it manually by running JMFRegistry after installing JMF.

[image]

or do it programmatically with the help of the extension library FMJ (Free Media in Java). Here is the code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.format.RGBFormat;
import net.sf.fmj.media.cdp.GlobalCaptureDevicePlugger;

public class FMJSandbox {
    static {
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", "D:/fmj-sf/native/win32-x86/");
        try {
            final Field sysPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
            sysPathsField.setAccessible(true);
            sysPathsField.set(null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GlobalCaptureDevicePlugger.addCaptureDevices(); 
        Vector deviceInfo = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(new RGBFormat());
        System.out.println(deviceInfo.size());
        for (Object obj : deviceInfo ) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
}
```